# Firebase App Check for Angular works on local but not deployable to firebase hosting

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-app-check

I try to integrate firebase App Check on my angular project. I have initialized app check using the following code on app.module.ts imports sections;

```
    provideAppCheck(() => initializeAppCheck(getApp(), {provider: new ReCaptchaV3Provider('xxxxxxxx'),      
  isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true })),
```

It works fine on my local but when I try to deploy it to firebase hosting using the command below;

```
firebase deploy --only hosting
```

I get the following error;

> Prerendering 6 route(s) to C:\dev\ai-diagnose-assistant\hosting\dist\ai-diagnose-assistant\browser...Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appendChild') ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then
> ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appendChild')
> at makeDiv (C:\dev\ai-diagnose-assistant\hosting\dist\ai-diagnose-assistant\server\main.js:1:4054192)
> at initializeV3 (C:\dev\ai-diagnose-assistant\hosting\dist\ai-diagnose-assistant\server\main.js:1:4054224)
> at ReCaptchaV3Provider.initialize (C:\dev\ai-diagnose-assistant\hosting\dist\ai-diagnose-assistant\server\main.js:1:4057853)
> at index_esm2017_activate (C:\dev\ai-diagnose-assistant\hosting\dist\ai-diagnose-assistant\server\main.js:1:4060053)
> at initializeAppCheck (C:\dev\ai-diagnose-assistant\hosting\dist\ai-diagnose-assistant\server\main.js:1:4060070)
> at C:\dev\ai-diagnose-assistant\hosting\dist\ai-diagnose-assistant\server\main.js:1:4036965
> at C:\dev\ai-diagnose-assistant\hosting\dist\ai-diagnose-assistant\server\main.js:1:4036951
> at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (C:\dev\ai-diagnose-assistant\hosting\node_modules\zone.js\bundles\zone.umd.js:412:30)
> at Zone.run (C:\dev\ai-diagnose-assistant\hosting\node_modules\zone.js\bundles\zone.umd.js:166:47)
> at NgZone2.runOutsideAngular (C:\dev\ai-diagnose-assistant\hosting\dist\ai-diagnose-assistant\server\main.js:1:2105206) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appendChild')
> at makeDiv (C:\dev\ai-diagnose-assistant\hosting\dist\ai-diagnose-assistant\server\main.js:1:4054192)
> at initializeV3 (C:\dev\ai-diagnose-assistant\hosting\dist\ai-diagnose-assistant\server\main.js:1:4054224)
> at ReCaptchaV3Provider.initialize (C:\dev\ai-diagnose-assistant\hosting\dist\ai-diagnose-assistant\server\main.js:1:4057853)
> at index_esm2017_activate (C:\dev\ai-diagnose-assistant\hosting\dist\ai-diagnose-assistant\server\main.js:1:4060053)
> at initializeAppCheck (C:\dev\ai-diagnose-assistant\hosting\dist\ai-diagnose-assistant\server\main.js:1:4060070)
> at C:\dev\ai-diagnose-assistant\hosting\dist\ai-diagnose-assistant\server\main.js:1:4036965
> at C:\dev\ai-diagnose-assistant\hosting\dist\ai-diagnose-assistant\server\main.js:1:4036951
> at _ZoneDelegate.invoke (C:\dev\ai-diagnose-assistant\hosting\node_modules\zone.js\bundles\zone.umd.js:412:30)
> at Zone.run (C:\dev\ai-diagnose-assistant\hosting\node_modules\zone.js\bundles\zone.umd.js:166:47)
> at NgZone2.runOutsideAngular (C:\dev\ai-diagnose-assistant\hosting\dist\ai-diagnose-assistant\server\main.js:1:2105206)
> ✖ Prerendering routes to C:\dev\ai-diagnose-assistant\hosting\dist\ai-diagnose-assistant\browser failed.

What could be the reason of that error?

Comment: This seems to be an unfixed issue with angularfire: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/3128. One of the comments says you need to use firebase admin on the server in order for this to work: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/3128#issuecomment-1332360013

Comment: I'm a bit confused, isn't it the very basic configuration what I have given at my question? am I doing something wrong or is angular/fire/appcheck simply broken? I have looked at the proposed solution, it installs and configure firebase-admin package which seems to be a bit overkill. I'm a bit new to App Check but what I want is to protect my firebase functions and only allow it to be requested by my app.

Comment: It is a basic configuration but it looks like `ReCaptchaV3Provider` doesn't work for SSR - it's only meant for the browser. That's also why the same Github issue has a workaround based on the platform that the app is running: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/3128#issuecomment-1046975893

Comment: I can deploy now but window.FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN = true; not seem to work. It doesn't give me debug token from browser console anymore. Is it because getToken returns nothing here;
  provider(siteKey: string) {
      return isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)
          ? new ReCaptchaV3Provider(siteKey)
          : new CustomProvider({
              getToken: () => new Promise(() => { })
          })

Comment: This workaround skips the `ReCaptchaV3Provider` for SSR only, so it should import it only in the browser. Do you inject `PLATFORM_ID`?